# Change Select Name after Row Clone

Tags: jquery, select, clone

I have a table row that a user can clone if they need additional rows, and the select name is increased via jQuery at the same time as the clone. However continually cloning the row doesnt increase the row count as it should.

Some help on this one would be really appreciated. Code Below.

```
function addRow() {
$("#addRow").live('click', function() { 
    var tr, clone, fields;
    tr = $(this).closest('.tr_clone');
    clone = tr.clone();

    tr.after(clone);
    tr.find('.addButton').empty();
    $("tr:last").css({backgroundColor: 'yellow', fontWeight: 'bolder'});
    fields = $("tr:last").find("select[name^='row-']");

    fields.attr('name', 'row-' + (fields.length + 1));
    name = fields.attr("name");

    alert(name);

});
}
```

Comment: Could you post sample on jsFiddle

Comment: It is here: http://jsfiddle.net/hycqj/6/ Its not running, not sure why, but it runs on my server fine. But it at least gives you an idea of the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try modifying this line

```
 fields.attr('name', 'row-' + ($('.tr_clone').length ));
```

On jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/hycqj/7/

Answer (score 0):

You did not call your javascript function

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   addRow();
});
```

Comment: I was calling it from another function. Just wasnt in the code above.